# Pi Day is approaching: What are some interesting math questions whose answer is exactly $\pi$?

Tags: big-list, recreational-learning

In anticipation of [Pi Day](https://www.piday.org/), which is (of course) March 14, I would like to ask:

> What are some interesting math questions whose answer is exactly $\pi$?

The questions can be for any age group.

Of course, any math question can be tweaked so that its answer is $\pi$. For example, "What is a closed form for $4\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2k-1}$ ?", where the $4$ is there just to force the answer to be $\pi$. But I'm asking for natural, untweaked questions whose answer is exactly $\pi$.

Here are some examples.

1. $n$ identical "sunrays" of edge length $1$ emanate from a circle of radius $1$, as shown here with example $n=8$.

[image]

What is $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}(\text{total area of rays})$ ?

I suppose this is not entirely trivial - unless you see the intuitive solution:

> Flip the sunrays inside the circle.

2. Evaluate $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin{x}}{x}dx$. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5248/evaluating-the-integral-int-0-infty-frac-sin-x-x-mathrm-dx-frac-pi) are some solutions.
3. The famous [colliding blocks](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138289/intuitive-reasoning-behind-pis-appearance-in-bouncing-balls) (or balls) question: "Let the mass of two balls be $M$ and $m$ respectively. Assume that $M=16 \times 100^n m$. Now, we will roll the ball with mass $M$ towards the lighter ball which is near a wall. How many times do the balls touch each other before the larger ball changes direction? (The large ball hits the small ball which bounces off the wall.)"

Comment: Are you sure the sun-ray example works? To my perception, truly flipping the rays should leave them with indented sides by the circle, not the circle itself... ?

Comment: @paulgarrett As the number of rays approaches infinity, the total area of the indentions approaches zero.

Comment: Oop, oh-so-true. :) Very good. :)

Comment: $\pi$ has taken the larger share of the pie. We need to work $e$ into the calendar, so that hopefully someone will find one simple presentation of it. How about an $e$ moment, to be celebrated at 2 pm, July 18th. Too bad schools are not open in July.

Comment: @Maesumi [UK schools are](https://www.eastsussex.gov.uk/education-learning/term-dates) but of course the date 7/18 doesn't exist outside North America. (And neither does 3/14, or even 31/4).

Comment: How many school students know what $e$ is? How many know what $\pi$ is? @Maesumi

Comment: @Shinrin-Yoku I think we should capture more of the calendar. It is about mathematics more than it is about $\pi$. Days for $\sqrt2, \sqrt3, \sqrt 5$, golden ratio, you name it. The more the merrier. And each country has a different calendar, it might not work for some region. There is no particular advantage to make it an international event.

Answer (score 10):

Regarding your second example. Not only $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x} dx = \pi$, but also
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x} \frac{\sin (x/3)}{x/3} dx = \pi $$
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x} \frac{\sin (x/3)}{x/3} \frac{\sin (x/5)}{x/5}dx = \pi $$
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x} \frac{\sin (x/3)}{x/3} \frac{\sin (x/5)}{x/5} \frac{\sin (x/7)}{x/7}dx = \pi $$
$$ \dots $$
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x} \frac{\sin (x/3)}{x/3} \frac{\sin (x/5)}{x/5} \frac{\sin (x/7)}{x/7} \dots \frac{\sin (x/13)}{x/13} dx = \pi . $$
And then the pattern breaks and we have
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x} \frac{\sin (x/3)}{x/3} \frac{\sin (x/5)}{x/5} \frac{\sin (x/7)}{x/7} \dots \frac{\sin (x/15)}{x/15} dx < \pi $$
specifically

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x} \frac{\sin (x/3)}{x/3} \frac{\sin (x/5)}{x/5} \frac{\sin (x/7)}{x/7} \dots \frac{\sin (x/15)}{x/15} dx \approx \pi - 4.62\times 10^{-11} $$
For the explanation, check the [Borwein integral on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borwein_integral) and [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=851U557j6HE&t=37s).

Comment: Well, that explains why I was unable to prove the general case by induction.

Comment: @Dan It ultimately boils down to when the sum of the fractions exceeds one, indeed picking a series that *never* exceeds one we would *always* have the result to be $\pi$.

Answer (score 6):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffon%27s_needle_problem

[image]

17 matches thrown randomly.  Spacing between lines is 1 match length.  11 cross a line.  $\frac{2 \cdot 17}{11} \approx 3.1 \approx \pi$.

Comment: Years ago, I worked with several colleagues as one of a few graduate student advisors on a batch of undergraduate research projects.  One of the groups was interested in generalizing this result to more spaces.  They wrote a nice little paper on the topic: https://arxiv.org/abs/2009.06755 .

Answer (score 5):

"What are some interesting math questions whose answer is exactly $\pi$?"

The area of a unit circle--It is exactly $\pi$.

The proof is very neat and visual and can be understood by *any* audience(which is is what separates it from other examples and makes it so important to know.):

[image]

Comment: That is, if you accept (or define) that $\pi$ is half the ratio of a circle's circumference to its radius.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg Yes that is the usual definition.

Comment: But this definition is not understood by every audience (which is what Torsten most likely meant to say with his comment).

Comment: @Jasper I think any audience with a middle school math education, should know it. Also, given the level of complexity of the other answers, don’t you think that this is a bit of a strawman?

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I’d address the same comment to you.

Comment: Fair enough. I'd just say that most people who know (or have seen and memorized) $C=2 \pi r$ would also know (or have seen and memorized) $A=\pi r^2$, and won't find that result surprising. Admittedly, this is a nice geometric idea to show that $A$ follows from $C$, although one should be careful giving people slick arguments involving limits, as per https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12906/the-staircase-paradox-or-why-pi-ne4 or https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1390891/false-proof-pi-4-but-why.

Comment: That being said, if the audience knows basic calculus, I find it much cooler to remind them of $A= \pi r^2$ and $C=2\pi r$ for the circle, as well as $V=\frac43 \pi r^3$ and $S=4 \pi r^2$ for the sphere, let them look at it for ten seconds, and then look at their faces when they realize that the measure of the boundary is the derivative of the measure of the inside. Kind of the other way around than your connection. But one of the formulae is taken for granted in each case.

Answer (score 4):

A favorite is:
[What fraction of the integer lattice can be seen from the origin?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/151706/6094).

The answer is about $61$%.
Here $\pi$ makes its appearance in a surprising, non-circular context
(surprising to me):

$$\frac{1}{\zeta(2)} = \frac{6}{\pi^2} \approx 0.6079 \;.$$

[image: LatticeVisib8Grid]

And $\frac{1}{\zeta(d)}$ in dimension $d$: Almost all the lattice points
are visible as $d$ grows (because $\zeta(d) \to 1$).

Comment: I've been pointed to the Basel problem video, which shows an underlying connection to circles: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-o3eB9sfls&ab_channel=3Blue1Brown).

Comment: Is there a reference book or article that explains this fact in depth and at length?

Answer (score 3):

On Youtube, there's a video about two squares, one of $1$kg. and one of $10^n$kg., who are bouncing between themselves and the Y-axis. apparently the amount of bounces equals the decimals of $\pi$:

Hereby the [Youtube URL](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HEfHFsfGXjs), uploaded by 3blue1brown.

Comment: This is number 3 in the OP, by the way, but still it's useful to have a Youtube video reference. You may want to add the author and the title, so that your answer is more self-contained.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, but more of a chuckle. The [Indiana Bill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Pi_Bill#:%7E:text=The%20Indiana%20Pi%20Bill%20is,mathematical%20truth%20by%20legislative%20fiat.) also gives $\pi$.

More seriously, it all depends on your audience. [There are many choices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulae_involving_%CF%80).  Some of your students might like the [the history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi) of $\pi$ as well.